# AppleDoc Categories not showing in quickhelp

Tags: xcode, categories, appledoc

I've succesfully generated a docset with AppleDoc by following the installation instructions. If i got into XCode Documentation Organiser, everything is there, including the categories:

[image]

But when I <kbd>⌥</kbd>-click on one of my category methods I see nothing but this:

[image]

I've tried a lot of things but none of these work:

- Adding --no-merge-categories
- Adding --merge-categories
- Changing filename extensions
- Restart XCode
- Restart macbook
- Search google (AppleDoc quickhelp categories)
- Search stackoverflow
- Search gitHub repository issue list (https://github.com/tomaz/appledoc)

Please help, because I want to generate documentation, and most of my library consists of categories. I'm using the latest AppleDoc (appledoc 2.1 (build 858)), and Xcode 4.6.3.

Edit: are there users actually using AppleDoc? Does the quick help actually work for you? I also note a lack of documentation even though the repository is updated regularly.

Comment: I've forked AppleDoc trying to find a fix... It looks promising..

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Have you came to a solution. Please help

Comment: Please see here for my solution: https://github.com/tomaz/appledoc/pull/375

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems nobody else is using appledoc but me. Anyway, it looks like it is a bug in XCode, i have pushed a workaround in github. Comment if you want details.

Update: my pull request has been accepted, check here for details:

- Pull request https://github.com/tomaz/appledoc/pull/375
- related issue: https://github.com/tomaz/appledoc/issues/374